# Merge rows with same id, different vallues in 1 column to multiple columns

Tags: pandas, merge, multiple-columns, rows

`what i have` length can be of different values/ so somethimes 1 id has 4 rows with different values in column val, the other columns have all the same values

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'val': ['06123','nick','@gmail','06454','abey','@gmail','06888','sisi'], 'media': ['nrc','nrc','nrc','nrc','nrc','nrc','nrc','nrc']})
```

`what i need`

```
id    kolom 1     kolom2   kolom 3   media
1     06123       nick     @gmail    nrc
2     06454       abey     @gmail    nrc
3     6888        sisi     None      nrc
```

I hope I gave a good example, in the corrected way, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('id').agg(list)
df2['col 1'] = df2['val'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else 'None')
df2['col 2'] = df2['val'].apply(lambda x: x[1] if len(x) > 1 else 'None')
df2['col 3'] = df2['val'].apply(lambda x: x[2] if len(x) > 2 else 'None')
df2['media'] = df2['media'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else 'None')
df2.drop(columns='val')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. Since your original dataframe doesn't have lists with the same length (which will get you a `ValueError`, you can define it as:

```
data = {"id":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
        "val": ["06123","nick","@gmail","06454","abey","@gmail","06888","sisi"], 
        "media": ["nrc","nrc","nrc","nrc","nrc","nrc","nrc","nrc"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
df = df.transpose()

>>> df
    id     val media
    0    1   06123   nrc
    1    1    nick   nrc
    2    1  @gmail   nrc
    3    2   06454   nrc
    4    2    abey   nrc
    5    2  @gmail   nrc
    6    3   06888   nrc
    7    3    sisi   nrc
    8    3     NaN   NaN
```

Afterwards, you can replace with `np.nan` values with an empty string, so that you can `groupby` your `id` column and join the values in `val` separated by a `,`.

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, "", regex=True)
df_new = df.groupby(["id"])["val"].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x)).reset_index()

>>> df_new
        id                val
    0  1.0  06123,nick,@gmail
    1  2.0  06454,abey,@gmail
    2  3.0        06888,sisi,
```

Then, you only need to transform the new `val` column into 3 columns by splitting the string inside, with any method you want. For example,

```
new_cols = df_new["val"].str.split(",", expand=True) # Good ol' split

df_new["kolom 1"] = new_cols[0] # Assign to new columns
df_new["kolom 2"] = new_cols[1]
df_new["kolom 3"] = new_cols[2]
df_new.drop("val", 1, inplace=True) # Delete previous val

df_new["media"] = "nrc" # Add the media column again
df_new = df_new.replace("", np.nan, regex=True) # If necessary, replace empty string with np.nan

>>> df_new
        id kolom 1 kolom 2 kolom 3 media
    0  1.0   06123    nick  @gmail   nrc
    1  2.0   06454    abey  @gmail   nrc
    2  3.0   06888    sisi     NaN   nrc
```